# What is the difference between is_convertible is_assignable

Tags: c++, type-traits

What is the difference between `is_convertible` and `is_assignable`?

Why,

in vs2012

```
is_convertible<int, int&> is false

is_assignable<int, int&> is true
```

in gcc4.7.2

```
is_convertible<int, int&> is false

is_assignable<int, int&> is false
```

Comment: `is_convertable<A, B>` is converting A to B, while `is_assignable<A, B>` is assigning B to A. Note how these are somewhat switched order of arguments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One difference is that the arguments are the other way round.

`is_convertible<From,To>` means that an expression of type `From` can be converted to type `To`. The standard defines this in terms of a function returning `To` containing a line `return create<From>();` where `create<From>()` returns a reference to `From`. So `is_convertible<int,int&>` is false, since you can't bind an *rvalue* `int` to a non-const *lvalue* reference `int&`.

`is_assignable<T,U>` means that an *rvalue* expression of type `U` can be assigned to an expression of type `T`; that is, that `t = u;` is well-formed. The expression to be assigned to is specified as a function call returning an *lvalue* reference if `T` is an *lvalue* reference, and an *rvalue* reference otherwise. This means that `is_assignable<T,U>` can only be true if `T` is a non-const *lvalue* reference type; hence being false for `<int,int&>`.

I would guess that VS2012 either allows assignment to *xvalues*, or uses a non-standard check for `is_assignable`, giving what I think is an incorrect result.

Note that in general convertible doesn't imply assignable, since there may be no accessible assignment operator; and assignable doesn't imply convertible, since there may be an assignment operator but no accessible conversion constructor or operator.

Comment: As I  pointed out in the other answer, it's vs2012 that's wrong, see: See the spec or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable. is_assignable adds r-value reference to the first parameter, so unless it's an l-value reference, it should return  false.

Comment: Am I confusing rvalue references and rvalues?

Comment: @yiding: I think I might be getting confused too. A careful reading of the standard seems to suggest that you and GCC are correct, however odd it seems.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a bug in gcc, `is_convertible` in this context means that:

```
int& foo()
{
    return 3; //invalid
}
```

On the other hand `is_assignable` in this context means that:

```
void foo(int& x, int y)
{
    y = x; // valid
}
```

Comment: Technically `is_assignable<int, int&>` tests that an rvalue-reference of int `(int&&)` can be assigned to from a reference of int. rvalue-references can't be assigned anything, and that's why it should be false.

Comment: Hm, `is_assignable<int, int&>` is defined as `declval<int>() = declval<int&>()` and `declval<T>` is a function that returns `add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`. So in this case, it's testing that an xvalue (function returning an rvalue reference) can be assigned to from an lvalue (function returning an lvalue reference). Right?

Comment: See the spec or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable
They give an explicit example showing the difference between `is_assignable<x, y>` vs `is_assignable<x&, y>`.