# Inconsistent results of is_assignable<>

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between is_convertible is_assignable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952404/what-is-the-difference-between-is-convertible-is-assignable)

I use this test code:

```
cout<<std::is_assignable<int, int>::value<<endl;
cout<<std::is_assignable<int, char>::value<<endl;
cout<<std::is_assignable<int&, int>::value<<endl;
cout<<std::is_assignable<int&, char>::value<<endl;
cout<<std::is_assignable<int, int&>::value<<endl;
cout<<std::is_assignable<int, char&>::value<<endl;
```

The result in vs2012 is:

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

In gcc4.7.2 I get:

```
false
false
true
true
false
false
```

Which result is correct according to the standard?

Answer (score 6):

`is_assignable<T,U>` is true if:

> The expression `declval<T>() = declval<U>()` is well-formed

`declval<T>` is declared as a function returning a reference to `T`:

```
template <class T>
  typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;
```

where `add_rvalue_reference<T>::type` is an *rvalue* reference type (`T&&`) if `T` is an object or function type, or `T` itself if it is a reference type.

This means that `is_assignable<T,U>` can only be true if `T` is a non-const *lvalue* reference type. If it's an object type, then `add_rvalue_reference<T>::type` is an *rvalue* reference type; so the expression `declval<T>()` is an *xvalue*, which cannot be assigned to.

So, unless I've misread the standard, GCC is correct and VS2012 is wrong. Even if it might seem to make more sense for `is_assignable<int,int>` to be true, it is not.

Comment: Yeah, this is a sad and misleading thing and I would bet the original intention was a different one, but it is now like it is. I fell for this once too and wrote my own assignable traits.

Comment: Maybe it should be renamed to `is_assignable_lvalue_reference<T,U>`. =/

Answer (score 3):

`is_assignable<T,U>::value` is defined as true when `declval<T>() = declval<U>()` is well-formed and `declval<T>` is defined as a function returning `add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`.

We must remember that an assignment is only valid for a modifiable lvalue as the left operand. Also remember the rules of reference collapsing (especially the last two):

```
T&  &  -> T&
T&& &  -> T&
T&  && -> T&
T&& && -> T&&
```

So each case:

1. `is_assignable<int, int>` and `is_assignable<int, char>`

   Can we assign the result of a function returning an rvalue reference (an xvalue) to the result of another function returning an rvalue reference (another xvalue). No we can't. This should be `false`.
2. `std::is_assignable<int&, int>` and `std::is_assignable<int&, char>`

   Can we assign the result of a function returning an rvalue reference (an xvalue) to the result of a function returning an lvalue reference (an lvalue). We sure can. This should be `true`.
3. `std::is_assignable<int, int&>` and `std::is_assignable<int, char&>`

   Can we assign the result of a function returning an lvalue reference (an lvalue) to the result of a function returning an rvalue reference (an xvalue). No we can't. This should be `false`.

So I say GCC is right here.