# Why is std::is_assignable counter-intuitive?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

`std::is_assignable<int, int>::value == false` in a conforming implementation (e.g. clang/libc++, gcc/libstdc++, but not VS2012).

Intuitively, this implies that an expression such as `int x = 3;` is invalid. But the specification of `is_assignable` states that both sides of the assignment are converted to `std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`, and so `std::is_assignable<int, int>::value` must evaluate to `false` (because `int` + `&&` -> `int&&`, which is an unassignable rvalue).

Why is `std::is_assignable` designed this way, or am I misunderstanding something about what `is_assignable<int, int>::value` really means?

Related discussions:

- [Inconsistent results of is_assignable<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955677/inconsistent-results-of-is-assignable/13955889).
- [What is the difference between is_convertible is_assignable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952404/what-is-the-difference-between-is-convertible-is-assignable/13952767).

Comment: `srd::is_assignable<int&,int>::value` is, however, `true`...  The question is not about construction but assignment.

Comment: `int x = 3;` is not an assignment right?

Answer (score 23):

In these traits, and with `T` not being an lvalue reference type, `T` implies an rvalue.

With many user-defined types `T`, it is perfectly reasonable to assign to rvalue types.  And it is even very useful in some contexts:

```
std::vector<bool> v(5);
v[0] = true;
```

In the above expression, `v[0]` is an rvalue which is getting assigned to.  And if `vector<bool>` is a poor example, then the following new C++11 code does the same:

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int>
do_something();

int
main()
{
    int i, j;
    std::tie(i, j) = do_something();
}
```

Above, the result of `do_something()` is being assigned to an rvalue `std::tuple`.  Assigning to rvalues is useful, and even common, though not done in the great majority of uses of assignment.

So `std::is_assignable` allows for the determining the distinction between being able to assign to an rvalue and to an lvalue.  If you need to know the difference, `std::is_assignable` can do the work for you.

If you are dealing with a more common case, such as just trying to figure out if a type `T` is copy assignable or not, then use `is_copy_assignable<T>`.  This trait is literally defined in terms of `is_assignable` and forces the lhs to an lvalue:

```
is_copy_assignable<T> == is_assignable<T&, const T&>
```

So `std::is_copy_assignable<int>::value` will be true as expected.

Use `is_copy_assignable` as your first choice, or `is_move_assignable` if you need that too.  Only when those traits don't work for you (perhaps because you need to look at a heterogeneous assignment), should you revert to using `is_assignable` directly.  And then you need to deal with the question of whether or not you want to allow rvalues on the lhs so as to account for cases that might involve a `vector<bool>::reference`, or a `tuple` of references.  You will have to explicitly choose whether or not you want to allow such cases in your is_assignable query.

For example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

int
main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_assignable<std::vector<bool>::reference&, bool>(),
        "Should be able to assign a bool to an lvalue vector<bool>::reference");

    static_assert(std::is_assignable<std::vector<bool>::reference, bool>(),
        "Should be able to assign a bool to an rvalue vector<bool>::reference");

    static_assert(std::is_assignable<bool&, std::vector<bool>::reference>(),
        "Should be able to assign a vector<bool>::reference to an lvalue bool");

    static_assert(!std::is_assignable<bool, std::vector<bool>::reference>(),
        "Should not be able to assign a vector<bool>::reference to an rvalue bool");
}
```

Comment: What you say implies that in fact the name is_assignable is misleading and might be more intuitive if named is_rvalue_assignable.

Nevertheless, thanks for the good explanation of this situation.

Comment: is_copy_assignable takes only a single template argument T, and thus doesn't seem to be an lvalue analog to is_assignable. There doesn't seem to be a type trait which tests if two types are truly assignable. That would seem to be more useful in general to users than having only a version that checks rvalue assignability.

Comment: @ThreeBit: `vector<bool>::reference` is a class type, not a `bool&`.  I've added explicit examples of use of `is_assignable` with these two distinct types.

Comment: @ThreeBit: The problem here is that C++ has something called "reference collapsing". It leads to several confusing situations, but the net result is that `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` does not always yield an rvalue reference. If the type is a prvalue (it has no reference qualifiers, `int`) or if the type is already an rvalue reference (`int &&`), the result is an rvalue reference. However, if the type is an lvalue reference (`int &`), then it evaluates to `int & &&`, which collapses down to `int &`.

Answer (score 7):

`std::is_assignable<int, int>::value == false` means that "an `int` literal cannot be assigned to an `int` literal" (among other things).

Your statement `int x = 3` is `std::is_assignable<int&, int>::value`.

For more info:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic answer is that you can get what you usually want by modifying your left argument.

The query `std::is_assignable_t<T&,U>` will tell you if you can reasonably write code such as:

```
T t;
U u;
t = u;
```

I say it's pragmatic because if they had written `std::is_assignable<>` to use a built-in lvalue reference on the left, it would have been more difficult to reuse this alternative to obtain its current functionality. It's simpler if the user adds an lvalue reference to an arbitrary type on the outside (it won't get erased) than to require an rvalue reference on the outside for a different query (which can easily be erased).

So, this version of `std::is_assignable<>` will answer your typical "lvalue receiving from rvalue" assignment test, but also more rare queries too.

The penalty for this flexibility is the counter-intuitive nature that you described.