# c++ - Why is nullptr_t not assignable to int*?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, nullptr

```
cout << std::is_assignable<int*, std::nullptr_t>::value << endl;
cout << std::is_assignable<int*&, std::nullptr_t>::value << endl;
```

The output is: **0 1**

I don't understand why the first check returns **false**

I can assign **nullptr** to a *reference to pointer*, but I cannot assign it to a raw *pointer*?

It's the inverse!

```
int* p = nullptr;
int*& pref = nullptr;
```

The second assignment, as expected, flags an error:

> **error:** cannot bind non-const **lvalue reference** of type **int*&** to an
>   **rvalue** of type **int***

Can someone explain me what is going on?

Comment: It is because you are trying to initialize a reference with nullptr, not assign to it. Don't let `=` confuse you.

Comment: I do not see any `int*` assignment here, but `int*&` and this sounds like erroneous.

Comment: Of course you cannot assign to `int*`.    Otherwise something like this would actually compile `int a = 1; &a = nullptr;`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on cppreference covers this.

`std::is_assignable<int, int>` is false but `std::is_assignable<int&, int>` is true.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable

Comment: Yes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920213/why-is-stdis-assignable-counter-intuitive), which GSerg [mentioned is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177674/c-why-is-nullptr-t-not-assignable-to-int#comment77323990_45177674)